# Find the column space and nullspace of matrix A

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I am quite a newbie when it comes to math and I'm now studying linear algebra.

I have a assignment, where I have to find the column space C(A) and nullspace N(A) for a matrix A.

\begin{bmatrix}a&b&c\\d&e&f\end{bmatrix}

I understand what the terms mean but I don't understand how should I proceed in finding the C(A) and N(A) for a given matrix.

For example, let Matrix A be the following matrix:

\begin{bmatrix}0&0&3\\1&2&3\end{bmatrix}

What is the process of finding C(A) and N(A)? Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finding the nullspace is in my opinion easier, because it amounts to solving an equation. More precisely, since the nullspace is the set of all vectors $x$ that the operation represented by matrix $A$ sends to the vector $0$, then you have the equation :

$$ x \in N(A) \Leftrightarrow Ax = 0 $$

Here your example is pretty simple because if you write this, with $x = \begin{pmatrix}a\\b\\c\end{pmatrix}$ :

$$
Ax = 0 \\
\Rightarrow \begin{cases}
3c = 0 \\
a + 2b + 3c = 0
\end{cases}
$$

You immediately see that the only solution to this is $a = -2b, c=0$, that is, all vectors multiple of $\begin{pmatrix}-2\\1\\0\end{pmatrix}$.

The column space, however, is a bit trickier. However, since it is the set of all vectors that have an antecedent by $A$, you could also write an equation on $y =  \begin{pmatrix}u\\v\end{pmatrix}$:

$$
y \in C(A) \Leftrightarrow \exists x, Ax = y \\
\Rightarrow \begin{cases}
u = 3c \\
v = a + 2b + 3c
\end{cases}\\
\Rightarrow v = a + 2b + u
$$

You can then see that for any vector in $\mathbb{R}^2$ you can find a corresponding vector $x$, which means that the columnspace of $A$ is $\mathbb{R}^2$.

The only thing to be very careful about is the dimensions of your vector : the null space is in $\mathbb{R}^3$ because your matrix has 3 columns, the columnspace is in $\mathbb{R}^2$ because your matrix has 2 rows.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the columns of $A$, the first and third columns are linearly independent, so they span $\mathbb{R}^2$. What does this tell you about the nullspace of $C(A)$?

For the rows of $A$, there are two linearly independent vectors in $\mathbb{R}^3$. The nullspace will be perpendicular to these two vectors, so just take the subspace spanned by the cross product of these two vectors.